# Showing an open cover $\{J_n\} = \{(a + \frac 1n, b - \frac 1n): n \in \mathbb N\}$ of $(a, b)$ has no finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Proof(?):

We want to show that $\forall N \in \mathbb N, \ (a, b) \not \subset \bigcup_{n = 1}^NJ_N.$ Note $\bigcup_{n = 1}^NJ_n = (a + \frac 1N, b - \frac 1N).$ But $(a, b) \not \subset J_N$ because $a + \frac{1}{2N} \in (a, b),$ but $a + \frac{1}{2N} \not \in J_n.$

My book says:

> For any $m > n, $ we have $a + \frac 1m < a + \frac 1n < b - \frac 1n < b - \frac 1m$ so that $J_n \subset J_m.$ Thus for any finite $N \in \mathbb N, \bigcup_{n=1}^N J_n = J_N = (a + \frac 1N, b - \frac 1N).$ But $(a, b) \not \subset J_N$ because $a + \frac{1}{2N} \in (a, b),$ but $a + \frac{1}{2N} \not \in J_n.$

Why do we need to show $J_n \subset J_m?$ Is it so that we can claim existence of some element in $(a, b)$ that is outside $G_n?$

Also, I am confused about the role of "Thus" in the quote above. Does it stand for implication like $J_n \subset J_m \implies \bigcup_{n=1}^N J_N = J_N?$ I don't think "Thus" here stands for implication because $\bigcup_{n=1}^N J_N = J_N$ doesn't depend on $J_n \subset J_m$ (does it?) and $J_N$ is defined in the problem statement.

Comment: The meaning of "thus" which you were unsure of is correct - it's an implication. The fact that $J_m \supset J_n$ for $m > n$ implies (you can use induction to prove this) that $J_N \supset \cup_{n=1}^{N} J_n$, and since we also obviously have $J_N \subset \cup_{n=1}^{N} J_n$, that gives the equality.

Comment: What?? If $b-a\geq 2$ then $S=\{(a+1/n, b-1/n): n\in \mathbb N\}$ is  $not$  a cover of $(a,b)$ because $a+1\in (a,b)$ \ $(\cup S).$ And if $0<b-a<2$ then $\{(a+1,b-1)\}$ is a one-member subset of $S$ and is  a cover of $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since $J_n\subset J_m$ whenever $n<m$, for all $1\leq n \leq N$ we have $J_n \subset J_N$, thus $\cup_{n=1}^{N}J_n=J_{N}$. Here the book uses $J_N$ because any fixed finite union of $J_i$s should be a subset of $\cup_{n=1}^{N}J_n$ for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$. However for that $N$, we can always have $a+\frac{1}{2N}$ which is an element of $(a,b)$, but not an element of $J_N$, thus not an element of the finite union.

Answer (score 0):

It's because if you have an increasing finite nest of sets, then their union is just the last set (it contains all of its predecessors in the nest).

If each set didn't contain its predecessor, then that wouldn't be true, because there would be a point in some prior member of the nest not contained in the last member, so the union would be *larger* than the last member alone.

The implication you mention is really "if $J_n\subset J_m$ whenever $n<m$, then $\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^N J_n = J_N$".